# Linux command to send HTTP API

Tags: linux, http

I would like to control a device on a home automation system with a external box. The API commands that works fine if I use a web browser are:

http://192.168.1.13/api/callAction?deviceID=34&name=turnOn
http://192.168.1.13/api/callAction?deviceID=34&name=turnOff

Is there a Linux command that I can use to call one of this HTTP?

Comment: You mean from the command line or a script? try `wget` or `curl`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the api endpoints could be designed better but if thats what you are stuck with this could work.

```
curl http://192.168.1.13/api/callAction?deviceID=34&name=turnOn 
curl http://192.168.1.13/api/callAction?deviceID=34&name=turnOff
```

Or in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X GET -G \
'http://192.168.1.13/api/' \
-d deviceID=34 \
-d name=name=turnOff
```

it might be better API design to have the endpoint in the form of

```
curl http://192.168.1.13/api/device/34/?action=on
curl http://192.168.1.13/api/device/34/?action=off
```

-OR-

```
curl http://192.168.1.13/api/device/34/on
curl http://192.168.1.13/api/device/34/off
```